# GTK# application crashes after adding a EventHandler

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I'm working on a little application in Mono. I'd like to have an image on a backrgound and everytime when window size is changing image has to be redrawn. But when I add a method for ExposeEvent or ConfigureEvent application falls. What might it be?
Here is my code

```
﻿using System;
using System.IO;
using Gtk;

public partial class AuthWind: Gtk.Window
{
    FileStream bgstream;
    public AuthWind () : base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        bgstream = File.Open ("noise-texture.png", System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        Build ();
        HBox mainCont = new HBox (false, 0);
        ConfigureEvent += DrawBG;
        Gdk.Pixbuf bgbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf(bgstream, this.Allocation.Width, this.Allocation.Height);
        Gdk.Pixmap bgmap = null;
        Gdk.Pixmap useless = null;
        bgbuf.RenderPixmapAndMask (out bgmap, out useless, 0);
        Style st = new Style ();
        st.SetBgPixmap (StateType.Normal, bgmap);
        this.Style = st;
    }

    void DrawBG(object obj, EventArgs e)
    {
        Gdk.Pixbuf bgbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf(bgstream, this.Allocation.Width, this.Allocation.Height);
        Gdk.Pixmap bgmap = null;
        Gdk.Pixmap useless = null;
        bgbuf.RenderPixmapAndMask (out bgmap, out useless, 0);
        Style st = new Style ();
        st.SetBgPixmap (StateType.Normal, bgmap);
        this.Style = st;
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search I have found a solution. Firstly pixbuf have to be created once and saved as class variable. Then in the event handler have to be used ScaleSimple method. It a method of a Pixbuf class. This method resize a pixbuf and create new one with width and height you need. As for event... It has to be added number of Gdk.Event in the window you want to work with. After that configure event has to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are keeping the `bgstream` open, but not rewinding the stream, maybe that crashes things?

Also, please post the full stack trace for the crash.

Comment: It might sound wierd, but now application compiles and run normal, but ConfigureEvent just doesn't start DrawBG method.